# What is the appropriate WAI-ARIA treatment for hidden elements?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

What would be the appropriate WAI ARIA treatment for hidden elements (hidden by CSS), such as loader images / 'please wait' text etc.? I would like to avoid these being read out by screen readers when initially hidden.

Comment: Just found the aria-hidden attribute. Do I then combine aria-hidden with aria-live for elements initially hidden but may be toggled visible from user action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`; both of these are widely supported by all major screenreaders. Note that if you're already using these - then you're done! There's no need to use aria-hidden in addition to these.

Be wary of other ways of hiding things: using large negative offsets/margins or zero heights/widths may work in one or two browser/screenreader combinations, but not all. So, for example, if you hide an element by animating its height to 0, be sure to set display:none or visibility:false at the end of the animation.

Here's some sources with this info:

- [Yahoo Accessibility Library](http://yaccessibilityblog.com/library/accessible-hiding-content.html)
- [WebAIM - Accessibility In Mind: CSS in Action: Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)